# React.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Component LoginForm have following code:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  .................................................................
    onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
      this.setState({ loading: true});
      this.props.submit(this.state.data).catch(console.log("errors"));

    }

    .....................................................................   
}

LoginForm.PropTypes = {
  submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default LoginForm;
```

When i submit button I get error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined**

Component **LoginPage**

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  submit = data => {
    this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="login-page">
        <main>
          <div className="login-block">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""/>
            <h1>Log into your account</h1>
            <LoginForm submit={this.submit} />
          </div>
          <div className="login-links">
            <a className="pull-left" href="user-forget-pass.html">Forget Password?</a>
            <a className="pull-right" href="user-register.html">Register an account</a>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, {login})(LoginPage);
```

**actions/auth**

```
import { USER_LOGGED_IN } from "../types";
import api from "../api";

export const userLoggedIn = user => ({
  type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
  user    
});

export const login = credentials => dispatch =>
  api.user.login(credentials)
    .then(user => dispatch(userLoggedIn(user)));
```

Can you please explain why undefined catch? Function submit return result with promise then().

Comment: you are returning the `.then` which is the result of the `.login` function

Comment: clearly because `this.props.submit` doesn't **return** anything

Comment: change `submit = data => {
    this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
  }` to `submit = data => this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));` or `submit = data => {
    return this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
  }`

Comment: @Sag1v no, there is nothing returned

Comment: read [arrow documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to learn the difference between having `{}` and not having `{}` - i.e. the `"concise body"`

Comment: @JaromandaX i was reffering to the `login` function, but you are right, the `submit` doesn't return anything just calling the `login`.

Comment: ahh, yes, didn't look that far @Sag1v

Comment: So basically you would have to return a `promise` from both `login` and `submit`.

Comment: thank you. i removed {}. Yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `catch` to the `LoginPage`:

```
submit = data => {
  this.props.login(data)
    .then(() => this.props.history.push("/"))
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

And pass the error to `LoginForm` as prop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the {} at the promise.
It should be like this

```
submit = data => this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push("/"));
```